# How to swipe using UISwipeGestureRecognizer to slide in and refresh the SAME uitableview

Tags: ios, sdk, uiscrollview, swipe, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I wish to update the UITableView's using a UISwipeGestureRecognizer's swipe... and make it look like it is sliding in from right (or left) then simply refresh the CURRENT UITableView's data with the new data.

Okay... here it is more detailed.  I have a UITableView inside a UINavigationController.  This table holds date-specific data -- mostly just things like notes for today, times and dates of meetings, etc.  I want to allow a right or left swipe (using UISwipeGestureRecognizer) to trigger a slide off of current table and a slide on of new table with the next day's events (or previous day...depending on side direction).  The way I was trying to do it is simply to have the current `ScheduleViewController` call itself AFTER setting the new date (`newDate`).  Okay, this works, KIND Of.  The swipeScheduleViewController does not fill the entire iphone screen.  It is missing the area of the tab bar at the bottom... and BECAUSE it is in a UINavigationController, going back FROM this tab and TO this tab causes issues.  PLUS this means an unspecifically LARGE number of new instances as the user goes forward and backward in time.  That is untenable.

```
ScheduleViewController *swipeScheduleViewController = [[[ScheduleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ScheduleView-iPhone" bundle:nil] retain];
swipeScheduleViewController.newDate = [NSDate date]; // (increment this or decrement it)
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.75;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
transition.delegate = self;
[self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[self.view addSubview:swipeScheduleViewController.view];
//[swipeScheduleViewController release]; // <-- leaving this in causes crash due to "Deallocated instance" during cellforRowAtIndexPath
```

So, then I was thinking:  Is there a way to set `newDate` (not the problem) and then refresh the current table , (here comes the problem: ) **SIMULATING** the slide in/out feature that one would expect.

OR am I thinking about this the total wrong way?  Someone earlier suggested a programmatically created UITableView inside a horizontally scrolling UIScrollView -- but this tableview I have has many things that are specific and hard to coordintate with anything other than a NIB linking the UIViews, etc to my properties inside the `.m` file

**EDIT**

Maybe I did not explain myself fully, so here goes:  I require the look of the entire table sliding off the screen and transitioning to another.  No if's and's or but's.  Thanks to those that suggested sliding rows...but they do not provide this flexibility...

I do not wish to seem ungrateful, but I am not fully understanding the method to have ONE nib/view that contains a UITableViw (within a UINavigationController) and pushing that off the screen -- replacing it with the SAME nib/view containing a UITableView.

The reason I am questioning, Matt, your solution is that unless I do NOT 'remark out' the `[swipeScheduleViewController release];` in the above code, I get the **"Deallocated instance" during cellforRowAtIndexPath** error.  This would seem to indicate that iOS is not keeping the  swipeScheduleViewController in memory and instantiated unless I release it.  Not releasing it, and thus preventing the crash -- results in the object in memory and thus a memory leak.  That is why I said it is dangerous to do (in comments to your answer)  Thanks Though!

Comment: The problems you are seeing is because what you are doing is so wrong. You are totally misusing a view controller. You must *never* just take a view controller and shove its view into your interface as you are doing here. Either use the built-in parent view controller types, or else devise your own parent view controller (container view controller) and perform the transition properly. You can readily transition views, yes, but do not misuse a view controller at the same time.

Comment: [meta] closed as too localized is BS. i have the same question.

Comment: stefann, please tap the "reopen" link if you think it should be reopened.  I did!  This was important for me.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`. One of the available animations is to slide in from the right (or left).

Comment: okay, maybe I am misunderstanding.  I can simply issue a tableview.reload  following setting the date.  I guess my question is more "how to simulate to push on and push off" screen of the uitableview without having a ton of tableviews instantiated?

Comment: If all the rows reload with an animation to the right, doesn't that look enough like the whole table reloaded by a swipe to the right?

Comment: btw:  `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` is not what I need.  I want the entire uitableview to slide to the left and the same one to slide in from the right.  `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` slides just a row. Thanks tho.

Comment: And in any case I don't see where your "ton" comes from. Even if you physically moved the whole table off screen and brought on a new one, that's just two table views for a second, and then just one after that.

Comment: You do not keep all the excess table views in a transition. There is just one view, then for a moment there are two, then there is one again. Dynamic creation and destruction of the views.

Comment: in fact I found this while searching for the same problem: a UITableView presents date-specific data, and implementing a swipe handler to traverse the dates does not provide sufficient feedback.  reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation is a good solution, also consider reloadSections:withRowAnimation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use swipe from up to down rather than from right to left , as the normal convention of swiping from right to left or left to right is to make transition from one view to another . Here is [the link](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pull-to-refresh-tableview) to rehresh tableview on swipe from up to down . Hope it will help you

Comment: Okay, maybe i am not explaining...swiping up to down reloads a table with the same or updated data.  left to right *on date specific situations* can easily be used to go from day to day (ie: today to tomorrow).  That is what i want to to.